# Problem reading excel file using SheetJS in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx, sheetjs

I'm trying to develop a simple Node.js app that takes and excel (xlsx) input file an writes out all of sheets within the workbook as separate csv files named as the sheets they came from. I'm used to working with xlsx and csv files with Python, but for several uninteresting reasons I want to use Node for this task.

[SheetJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) says it can do what I need it to and seems quite popular. I have made a basic start and can read in an xlsx and display the contents of the first sheet in the console as csv data.

This works fine on a small test file I made, but when I use a 'real life' file that will be run through my app, I only get the header record then a few dozen blank lines:

[Console results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smolo.png)

This must be down to some formatting within the workbook, as when I copy and paste the values only to a new sheet and read this in (i.e ...SheetNames[1]) I get the expected data back.

Here is a screenshot of the problematic file (obviously I've obscured the data for privacy):

[Excel workbook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Bxi.png)

Looking at the results in the console in my first screenshot, I can see there are a couple of empty columns and I'm aware there are a few dozen blank lines rows after the data, but there should be 14 rows displaying in the console that contain actual data.

The reason this app is required is so the files can be split out to csv's automatically, but at the moment I am stuck, unless I open the excel file and remove the formatting, essentially rendering the app pointless as it's supposed to automate the processing of these files.

I suppose my question is; is there a way to read xlsx files using Node regardless of any formatting?

Here is my starter code:

```js
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const workbook = XLSX.readFile('example.xlsx');
const csvData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);

console.log(csvData);
```

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Thanks,

RustySpoon

Comment: I know this is quite a niche issue, but any other suggestions on how to tackle this problem would be much appreciated, i.e. a different library to XLSX you could recommend? Or is there a way to load an xlsx to strip all formatting to get around this?